# alias with bash involving current system time

Tags: linux, bash, git, macos

I have the problem with macOS mojave, but I guess it generalizes to all bash environment. In the .bashrc or .profile, I add one line as:

```
alias gc="git add .;git commit --message="$(date +"iMac_%D_%T")""
```

My purpose is to send the current system time as a message when commiting a change by typing **gc**. However, the system time was read when **alias** was invoked (here is when I log in the system). 
Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The timestamp is part of the commit metadata by default. Why add an extra copy in the message?

Comment: Just notice this. Thank you for telling me this. I am quite new with git. I wrote this just because I am tired of typing the commit message. I am the only user of the codes. I change sth quickly on my local computer and then sync with the computation server, where I run them and check the results. This sometimes may happen many times in 10 minutes. If the time stamps are already there, maybe I just use iMac is OK.

Comment: "the system time was read when alias was invoked" ...Im not able to reproduce this on 10.14.3.

Comment: @RichardBarber, be sure when trying to reproduce it that you're duplicating the quoting style shown by the OP. Using single quotes instead of double quotes on the outside of the assignment would suppress the effect (though unlike the function approach, it would have a side effect of changing the meaning of literal single quotes used in the command).

Comment: @RichardBarber, ...see https://ideone.com/392qii, showing the OP's unmodified code running with their stated behavior (encoding the time the assignment was performed into the alias's text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler approach is to make this a shell function and not an alias at all:

```
gc() {
  git add . && git commit --message="$(date +"iMac_%D_%T")" "$@"
}
```

That said, as a matter of good `git` hygeine, I strongly advise against doing this; you'll get output files and temporary files you don't want checked in. `git commit -a`, by not adding new files, is somewhat safer -- though using `git add -p` to review changes hunk-by-hunk is by far the best practice to avoid mixing unrelated and unwanted changes into your commits.

Comment: Thank you Charles, or Dr. Duffy. It's my first question, and I am so happy that it was answered in such a perfect way. First, it works, my problem solved! Second, I learn more about linux and git. My background is biology/medicine, so I used quick and dirty solutions in programming. I will try to be a more professional programmer in the future:)